# Colouring objects and roots of polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, permutations, contest-math, roots

I found this question-

> Suppose $o_1,o_2,\dots , o_n$ are $n$ objects. We colour each object with a single
> colour. Say for $o_i$, the number of objects having the same colour as itself
> (including $o_i$) is $c_i$. Now we form a monic polynomial whose roots are $-c_1,-c_2,\dots ,-c_n$. Say the polynomial is
> $$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_1x+a_0$$
> Now, say exactly $k$ colours were used. Then which of the following is/are always true
>
> **A.** $k>a_0$
>
> **B.** $ka_0=a_1$
>
> **C.** $k=a_{n-1}$
>
> **D.** $ka_1=a_0$

I couldn't make much progress apart from noticing that since $c_i>0 \;\forall i\in \{1,2,\dots ,n\}$, all the roots of the polynomial are negative. So, using Descarte's rule of signs, we can say that the $a_i$'s are of alternating signs. But, I can't proceed anymore from here.

Also, putting $k=1$ (and so, $c_1=c_2=\dots =c_n=n$), we can easily eliminate options **A** and **C**. But, I want a real proof of the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the root $c_i$ occurs with multiplicity $c_i$ in the polynomial by definition: there are exactly $c_i$ objects with the color of $o_i$, and for any of these $c_i$ objects, there are exactly $c_i$ objects of that color.

Suppose that the set of $k$ distinct colors is $[k]=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. For each $r\in [k]$, let $S_r$ be the set of $i\in[n]$ for which $o_i$ is of color $r$.
The above observation implies that for any $i,j\in S_r$, $c_i = c_j$.

Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{c_i} &= \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j \in S_k} \frac{1}{c_j} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k} 1 = k.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, $k = \sum_{i=1}^n 1/c_i = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_1c_2\cdots c_{i-1}c_{i+1} \cdots c_n\right)/(\prod_{i=1}^n c_i) = a_1/a_0$ and $a_1 = ka_0$.

Comment: That's a great solution (+1). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are exactly $k$ colors. Then there is a partition of $n$ with $$\sum_{j=1}^k d_j=n$$ and $$f(x)=\prod_{j=1}^k(x+d_j)^{d_j}.$$ It boils down to showing that $$a_1=f'(0)=kf(0)=ka_0.$$

Comment: That's a great solution (+1). Thanks!